# Cant get data binding between Factory, controller and directive to work

Tags: angularjs

So think I am doing the right thing.

Basically, I have a factory that (among other things) gets some data form the API basically a large JSON type object with a ton of stuff using restangular. 
This is then stored in $scope.cvSkills. $scope.cvSkills is initiated in the beginning of the controller.

```
knowledge.controller('cvedit', function ($scope, cvFactory){
    $scope.iAm = "";
    $scope.CV = "";
    $scope.cvskills= "";       
    cvFactory.getSkills(function(cvSkills){
        $scope.cvskills = cvSkills;
        console.log("got " + $scope.cvskills.length);
    })

})
```

My problem is now getting the updated data to the directive so we can get d3 to make a nice tree. 
Tried:

```
knowledge.directive('skillTree', function(){
    function link(scope,element, attr){
        scope.$watch('attr.cvSkills', function() {
            console.log("CVSkills updated " + attr.cvSkills.length);
        });

        var cvSkills = attr.cvSkills;
        console.log("Got this back " + cvSkills.length);
        for (var i in cvSkills) {
            console.log("ID: " + i + " DATA: " + cvSkills[i])
        }
    }
    return {
        link: link,
        //scope: { cvskills: '=' },
        restrict: 'E'

    }
```

Problem is that the scope watch and the data passed in is whatever cvskills was initiated as, so how do I get it to react to updates?

```
<skill-tree cv-skills="{{cvskills}}"></skill-tree>
```

This is how I call it, so SHOULD it react, or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<skill-tree cv-skills="cvskills"></skill-tree>
```

So for this to work we need to make a couple changes to your directive.

```
knowledge.directive('skillTree', function()
{
    function link(scope)
    {
        scope.$watch('cvSkills', function (cvSkills) // we're watching the scope's cvSkills not the attribute's
        {
            console.log("Got this back " + cvSkills.length);

            for (var i in cvSkills)
            {
                console.log("ID: " + i + " DATA: " + cvSkills[i])
            }
        }, true);
    }

    return {
        link: link,
        scope: {
            cvSkills: '=' // this was correct, almost
        },
        restrict: 'E'
    }
});
```

I notice you tried adding `cvSkills` to your scope which was certainly a good start as that's what we need to `$watch` rather than the element's attribute.

Comment: Maybe it will still work but I don't think the curly braces are necessary in the html: `<skill-tree cv-skills="cvskills"></skill-tree>`

Comment: Thank you very much, will try this in a little while. Got a little bit confused by the examples what part was suppose to point to what. Thanks for some great help.

Comment: Well, doing something else wrong now. So it kind of works, and as far as I can tell, it is picking up the change at the right time. However, if I use the curly brackets I get Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{cvskills}}] starting at [{cvskills}}].. And without, it reads it as a 8 byte long string (saying cvskills). Checking $scope.cvskills it reports it is an object thought

Comment: Missed copying the cvskills into a variable (function(cvSkills) as in your example, just missed it ), once that was done, and without the {{ }} it worked a charm